# C++ fstream read result can't compare

Tags: c++, string, compare, fstream

I'm writting a little program to add Cartesian coordinates to an existing NC Code file in C++. I begin with a very simple prototype to "catch" the G-Code functions (G0, G1, G20, etc.), which are displayed in a .xll file which is basically a text file. Basically, 1 line would look like this:

G0 X=390.7248 Y=209.99 Z=-6.35 T=1001 E=1

So when I see a G0 instruction at the begining of a line, I know its a "rapid travel instruction" in G-Code. However, all my compare functions ain't seem to work when I compare the result I'm getting from the fstream read when there are more then 1 char. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

    char c;
string w = "";
fstream myfile(PATH);

        while (myfile.get(c))
    {
        //cout << c;
        if (c == ' ') {
            //Evaluate expression
            cout << w << "\n";  //Debug

            if (w.compare("H") == 0) {
                cout << "header found\n";
            }
            else if (w.compare("G0") == 0) {
                cout << "rapid travel instruction found\n";
            }
            else if (w.compare("G1") == 0) {
                cout << "linear interpolation instruction found\n";
            }
            else {
                cout << "Compare to G0 =" << w.compare("G0") << "\n";
                cout << "Compare to G1 =" << w.compare("G1") << "\n";
            }

            cout << "w reseted\n";  //Debug
            w = "";
        }
        else {
            //Build expression
            w = w + c;
        }
    }
```

Only the "H" seems to be working. In the console, when I cout the w before comparing, I get G0 and G1 correctly but never gets inside the if statement when comparing. There doesn't seem to have any invisible characters too.

Any ideas? I'm suspecting some something like my const string G0 or G1 are not formatted the same as the ones read from the file. Thank you.

Comment: This question's shown code fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for showing a [mre]. Because of that it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You need to [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part, this includes any ancillary information, like any input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: Most likely, the file does not contain what you expect. Print `w` surrounded by visible delimiters, and include `w.size()` in the output.

Comment: Also, `w.compare("H") == 0` —> `w == "H"` since you don't care about the ordering.

Answer (score 1):

While you can build up a string one character at a time like you're currently trying to do, it's going to be fairly tricky to get it right.

You could, instead, start by reading a string that will stop when you encounter white space in the file:

```cpp
std::string s;
while (myfile >> s) {
    if (s == "H") // ...
    else if (s == "G0") // ...
    else if (s == "G1") // ...
}
```

This will at least let you get started, but if I recall correctly, the file format you're dealing with is really line-oriented. That being the case, you generally want to read an entire line at a time, then read pieces out of that line:

```cpp
std::string line;
std::string s;

// read a line from the file:
while (std::getline(myfile, line)) {

    // create a stream to read pieces from that line:
    std::istringstream linereader(line);

    //process a line from the file by looking at what it contains:
    while (linereader >> s) {
        if (s == "G0") // ...
        else if (s == "G1") // ...
        // and so on
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank's for the string stream course! Works perfectly. I tried analysing char by char I thought maybe I has a \n before the G0 or G1 but no success. The istringstream made the trick the output is good.